# How to bind DataGridTemplateColumn.Visibility to a property outside of DataGrid.ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, wpfdatagrid

I need to bind the `Visibility` of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to a property outside of the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`,because i need to bind this column in the all the rows to one property inside the `ViewModel`,but as far as i know you just can bind that to something inside the `ItemsSource` or you should use `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle`
I've Already tried this code:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="post" 
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ProjectPostVisibility
                    , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MvvmCommonControl:DataGrid}}"/>
```

And i'm Sure my binding is correct because it works fine when i bind the `DataGridCell.Visibility` like below:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="post">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding DataContext.ProjectPostVisibility,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MvvmCommonControl:DataGrid}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn >
```

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Comment: @ AbZy:I added some code above.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your binding is correct, but it won't work with `DataGridTemplateColumn` directly because it's not in the visual tree. So it's not inherting `DataContext`.

You need to bind the `DataGridTemplateColumn` from code behind. [Here is a demo](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) that shows a way of doing it.

Comment: AbZy:Thank you so much.I didn't know that,and it was really interesting!

Answer (score 9):

As mentionned in other answers, the column isn't part of the visual/logical tree and doesn't inherit from `FrameworkElement` meaning it has no `DataContext`. That's why your binding doesn't work.

However you can add a dummy (collapsed) `FrameworkElement` at a level where the `DataContext` is what you're looking for (so taking your example, it'd be at the DataGrid's level), collapse it and use it as the Source of your Binding with the [`x:Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.reference?view=net-5.0) markup extension.

Here's an example :

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="Proxy" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="post" 
            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ProjectPostVisibility, Source={x:Reference Name=Proxy}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this setter in the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle and done:

```
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding DataContext.isVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```

If you need more help look at my example below. 
I want the Remove button to not be visible at the project level. First you have to make sure you have a isVisible property in your view model:

```
  private System.Windows.Visibility _isVisible;
    public System.Windows.Visibility isVisible
    {
        get { return _isVisible; }
        set
        {
            if (_isVisible != value)
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("isVisible");
            }
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
  if (isProj == false)
            this.model.isVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            this.model.isVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  >
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
               <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Content="X">
                 <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                         <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
                     </Style>
                 </Button.Style>
            </Button>
         </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
               <Setter Property="Background"  Value="Red"/>
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding DataContext.isVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
        </Style>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: But there needs to be also this (for header text to reflect visible binding):

    `<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.isVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
     </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>`

Comment: Thanks. Both the response and the comment from @psulek helped.

Comment: While this solution seems to be great, be aware that it does not hide the column ifsef, but only it's content.