# DataGrid Column Visibility is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to control the visibility of a DataGridTemplateColumn using IsVisible Property inside the ViewModel.
Here is the xaml code

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
         <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="32" IsReadOnly="True"
                            Visibility="{Binding  Path=Data.IsVisible,TargetNullValue=True,Source={StaticResource Proxy},Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"   CellTemplate="{StaticResource RemoveButtonTemplate}">
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my binding proxy

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
                                     typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

Here is the Viewmodel property

```
public bool IsVisible
        {
            get { return true; }           
        }
```

Every first time when i load the grid the DataGridTemplateColumn is always hidden. Please advice if i am doing some thing wrong.

Strange thing is that it works perfectly if i use FrozenColumnCount in xaml.

Comment: This might give some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310788/3047078

Comment: @FlatEric I am using binding Proxy as mentioned in the thread. Still no luck :(

Comment: Could it be as simple as a P vs p -- Source={StaticResource Proxy} and x:Key="proxy". Or was that just a typo in the question?