# Cannot hide DataGridTemplate using trigger

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to hide the `Column` contained in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` using a `Trigger`, in particular if the value of `DownloadType` is `false` the `Column` should not appear in the `DataGrid`, the problem's that I can still see even if the value is `False`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CanUserAddRows="false" 
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ClubController.ClubsStadium}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserResize="False">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DownloadType}" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource NullImageConverter}}" 
                         Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both"
                         Width="150" Height="150"
                         RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: did you try to move the trigger into the `DataTemplate` ? I think DataTemplate is overwriting the style

Comment: @Bijan yep, but same result :\

Comment: Aha! you want the column to disappear, but the trigger just **hides** the **cell**. you have to change the visibility of the **column** to **collapsed**

Comment: @Bijan could you please show me an example?

Comment: it turned out to be more complicated than I thought. see this http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/ taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15310788/366064